# How to recover data from a lost partitioned drive with BitLocker?

Tags: data-recovery, bitlocker, window

I have formatted the whole of my external hard drive. It had two partitions on the drive, the first one (200GB) was locked by BitLocker and another (800GB) didn't lock.

The model of the hard drive is `WD My Passport Ultra - 1TB Black`.  Now, I just have an unlocked partition with 931GB which is empty. In addition, I know the password/key of that locked partition. Fortunately, I write nothing to the drive after formating.
Now, I recovered my data form the second partition which wasn't locked (800GB).

Also, I found [this link](https://www.m3datarecovery.com/bitlocker-drive-data-recovery/recover-data-from-windows10-bitlocker-protected-partition.html). It just recovers data if you just formatted only the locked partition, not whole the drive (repartitioned!).

How can I recover that locked partition? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem were you trying to solve by formatting the drive if you actually wanted the data?

Comment: @Ramhound It has happened by mistake!

Comment: You accidentally formatted your entire drive? Hopefully, you have backups, because even with the recovery key data recovery will be extremely difficult.  TestDisk might help but you might be better off sending it for professional data recovery.  Hope you didn’t actually download that linked software